# Production Deployment: Firebase invalid api key error in console

Tags: reactjs, firebase, environment-variables

I have deployed my web app on netlify but the site only shows a blank white page with following error in console.

Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

```
at F_ (assert.ts:142:44)
at U_ (assert.ts:167:30)
at new e (auth.ts:56:5)
at e.instanceFactory (index.ts:82:16)
at e.value (provider.ts:318:33)
at e.value (provider.ts:115:21)
at e.value (firebaseApp.ts:138:21)
at t.<computed> [as auth] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:185:29)
at Object.o [as auth] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:166:32)
at firebase.utils.js:39:30
```

I have doubled checked all the firebase config variables in my app, they are correct. I have also set the env variables on netlify. The app runs successfully on localhost. If the environment variables were not correct the site won't compile on localhost.

Localhost:

[image]

Deployment on netlify:

[image]

The environment variables set on netlify app.

[image]

All the environment variables set on netlify have been double checked. They are the same as in .env file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when the API key provided in the Firebase configuration is invalid
It is possible that the environment variables are not being correctly passed to the application during the build process on Netlify
You can try adding the environment variables declared in your .env.local file to Netlify as well  Another way to solve this issue is by relocating the .env.local file from the src folder to the root folder. I hope  these solutions  resolve the issue

Comment: .env file is already in the root folder. I have checked the environment variables set on netlify there are same as .env file. If the api key provided by firebase is invalid how would I resolve that

Comment: you can try regenerating a new API key from the Firebase console to see if that resolves the issue. Here’s how you can do it:

Go to the Firebase console and select your project.
Click on the gear icon in the top left corner and select “Project settings”.
Scroll down to the “Your project” section and click on the pencil icon next to “Web API Key”
Click on “Regenerate key” and confirm that you want to regenerate the key.
Update your environment variables on Netlify and in your .env file with the new API key